# SYCL: Runtime-Error when initialising a queue

Tags: c++, sycl

When initialising a queue in SYCL with ComputeCpp I get a Runtime-Error using Visual Studio 2022. Also I tried exact the same code used on the [Codeplay Guide](https://developer.codeplay.com/products/computecpp/ce/guides/sycl-guide/hello-sycl). I'm able to trigger this error just by initialising a queue, without selecting any device or something else. (selecting one doesn't help either)

```
#include <CL/sycl.hpp>
int main(int, char**) {
    cl::sycl::queue queue;

    return 0;
}
```

`(Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF92F544FD9 in LearningComputeCpp.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_array_new_length at memory location 0x0000005986CFF110.)`

I installed ComputeCpp using the [Windows installer](https://developer.codeplay.com/products/computecpp/ce/home) and manually included it, aswell as OpenCL.
(I'm using an AMD Radeon HD7900 GPU)

Answer (score 0):

To find out if you have a supported processor with drivers that can be used by ComputeCpp, use the "computecpp_info" command. Instructions can be found [here](https://developer.codeplay.com/products/computecpp/ce/guides/platform-support-notes/getting-started-with-computecpp-for-windows) and this will show whether your device is supported.

The AMD drivers don't support SPIR fully though so I expect you will not be able to use this GPU with ComputeCpp.

Alternatively you could use [DPC++](https://github.com/intel/llvm/blob/sycl/sycl/doc/GetStartedGuide.md#build-dpc-toolchain-with-support-for-hip-amd) or [hipSYCL](https://github.com/illuhad/hipSYCL), both of which support AMD GPUs.

Comment: According to "computecpp_info" my GPU wasn't tested on my OS. Sadly I couldn't get DPC++ or hipSYCL to run on my system. I gues I'll stick to OpenCL or Compute Shaders. I'm just trying to create a small educational project.